# Creating bash scripts that take arguments

Tags: bash

I know how to ask questions in bash like "Would you like to create a directory" and based on that input do something. But I would like to create a bash script where I could do:

```
./somescriptname.sh install
./somescriptname.sh update
./somescriptname.sh assets get asset-name
./somescriptname.sh install
./somescriptname.sh update
./somescriptname.sh assets get all
```

I am not really sure how to read command line arguments passed in using bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$1`, `$2`, etc. for accessing command-line arguments:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Arg 1: $1"
echo "Arg 2: $2"
echo "All args (as one string): $*"
echo "All args (passed to echo each as a different argument): $@"
```

Comment: And quote them properly.

Answer (score 1):

you get the args from $1,$2, $3 ...
arg $0 is the script name

for example. this takes 3 args. if $3 is not present nothing is printed.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "the $1 eats a $2 every time there is a $3"
echo "bye:-)"
```

if this is foo.sh:
then on the command line just do: ./foo.sh boy spinach meal

also you should learn get ops so you can easily test the 'arguments'. since you have more than one. you may want to give each arg a definition. 
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial

Answer (score 1):

From Bash Reference Manual: **[Positional Parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Positional-Parameters.html#Positional-Parameters)**

> A positional parameter is a parameter denoted by one or more digits, other than the single digit 0. Positional parameters are assigned from the shell’s arguments when it is invoked, and may be reassigned using the set builtin command. Positional parameter N may be referenced as ${N}, or as $N when N consists of a single digit.